# Repeated measures in time ANOVA

Tags: r, anova

I have a simple dataset with two treatments (trt), 3 reps and repeated measures at different dates. The response variable is yield. We are looking for differences in treatment.
I understand that my repeated measures are nested into the rep, and a simple anova like aov(yield~trt) is not appropriate since it would treat each repeated measure as an independent rep. 
I think that I have to specify an error term, with date nested in rep, but I'm confused with the syntax.

This is my code

```
summary(aov(data=yi,yield~trt + Error(rep/date)))  #this means date nested in rep
```

Thank you for all your help!

This is my dataset

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17676, 17680, 17683, 17687, 
17690, 17695, 17698, 17702, 17705, 17709, 17712, 17716, 17719, 
17723, 17726, 17730, 17733, 17737, 17740, 17744, 17747, 17751, 
17754, 17759, 17761, 17765, 17768, 17772, 17775, 17779, 17782, 
17676, 17680, 17683, 17687, 17690, 17695, 17698, 17702, 17705, 
17709, 17712, 17716, 17719, 17723, 17726, 17730, 17733, 17737, 
17740, 17744, 17747, 17751, 17754, 17759, 17761, 17765, 17768, 
17772, 17775, 17779, 17782, 17676, 17680, 17683, 17687, 17690, 
17695, 17698, 17702, 17705, 17709, 17712, 17716, 17719, 17723, 
17726, 17730, 17733, 17737, 17740, 17744, 17747, 17751, 17754, 
17759, 17761, 17765, 17768, 17772, 17775, 17779, 17782, 17676, 
17680, 17683, 17687, 17690, 17695, 17698, 17702, 17705, 17709, 
17712, 17716, 17719, 17723, 17726, 17730, 17733, 17737, 17740, 
17744, 17747, 17751, 17754, 17759, 17761, 17765, 17768, 17772, 
17775, 17779, 17782, 17676, 17680, 17683, 17687, 17690, 17695, 
17698, 17702, 17705, 17709, 17712, 17716, 17719, 17723, 17726, 
17730, 17733, 17737, 17740, 17744, 17747, 17751, 17754, 17759, 
17761, 17765, 17768, 17772, 17775, 17779, 17782, 17676, 17680, 
17683, 17687, 17690, 17695, 17698, 17702, 17705, 17709, 17712, 
17716, 17719, 17723, 17726, 17730, 17733, 17737, 17740, 17744, 
17747, 17751, 17754, 17759, 17761, 17765, 17768, 17772, 17775, 
17779, 17782), class = "Date"), yield = c(990, 1560, 1520, 1845, 
1820, 2260, 1175, 1630, 1305, 2065, 1060, 2060, 1565, 1755, 1380, 
1875, 1590, 1640, 1185, 1585, 830, 2055, 1285, 2555, 1230, 2095, 
1565, 1935, 1235, 1510, 1570, 660, 1010, 720, 1370, 1305, 1670, 
1120, 1780, 1210, 1675, 1600, 1490, 1010, 1060, 985, 1075, 915, 
1640, 895, 1535, 1330, 1990, 980, 2270, 1135, 1525, 1180, 1020, 
1010, 1050, 710, 975, 1290, 1115, 785, 1625, 1705, 1235, 1700, 
1430, 1175, 1115, 1275, 1035, 1085, 1185, 1475, 870, 1580, 845, 
1560, 635, 2315, 800, 2365, 945, 1515, 1435, 1855, 1355, 1585, 
1315, 745, 1125, 655, 1085, 1430, 1980, 985, 1675, 1090, 1510, 
1085, 1730, 1065, 1460, 795, 1345, 1165, 1145, 655, 1310, 645, 
1780, 945, 2375, 950, 1805, 1760, 1510, 1590, 1515, 1030, 645, 
1681, 750, 985, 1065, 1350, 875, 1520, 1045, 1800, 1165, 2070, 
1410, 1435, 1490, 1705, 1230, 1865, 1015, 1740, 745, 1275, 1180, 
2030, 755, 1540, 1410, 1340, 1155, 1495, 1160, 1335, 1030, 690, 
1330, 1005, 1240, 1190, 1625, 965, 1565, 1195, 1305, 1180, 1255, 
1090, 1675, 1250, 1615, 595, 1395, 695, 1600, 1165, 2215, 675, 
1300, 1190, 1035, 985, 985, 935), trt = c("117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", "117 lb/ac Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", "No Preplant", 
"No Preplant"), rep = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -186L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are interested in `yield ~ trt`, but the data are not independent because there are multiple measurements of each `rep`.

As far as I can tell from inspecting your data, the only nesting that occurs is that of `trt` in `rep`. If you model this as follows, it will be taken into account automatically:

```
require(lme4)
LMM <- lmer(yield ~ trt + (1 | rep), data = yi)
summary(LMM)

# or:
LMM <- aov(data = yi, yield ~ trt + Error(rep))
summary(LMM)
```

If you are concerned that the yield depends on the date, this could be modeled as a fixed effect, because the repeated measures are already taken into account by `(1 | rep)`. Moreover, think of what it would mean for `date` to be a random effect: If you were to repeat this experiment, would you randomly pick new dates? Do the dates come from some larger distribution of dates that cause a normally distributed offset of your yield? It seems more likely that there is a seasonal effect of `date`,* which you could model e.g. like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61032/176202).

* Try: `plot(yield ~ date, yi, pch = paste(rep), col = factor(trt))`